# Could not send nested multi dimensional json object POST request in PHP because multi dimensional json corrupted when converting it to array

Tags: php, json, api, post, crud

I have a nested multi dimensional json object and I want to make a post request with this json
but I did not find a direct way to send post request with this json because I did not find a way to declare a json object in php and even i cant convert this **json_object** to array because of the posted data corrupted

> ```
> json_object={
>     "messages": {
>         "authentication": {
>             "productToken": "your product token"
>         },
>         "msg": [{
>             "body": {
>                 "type": "auto",
>                 "content": "Fallback Text for SMS"
>             },
>             "to": [{
>                 "number": "00316012345678"
>             }],
>             "from": "00316098765432",
>             "allowedChannels": ["WhatsApp"],
>             "richContent": {
>                 "conversation": [{
>                     "text": "A text message with *bold* formatting in a speech bubble."
>                 }, {
>                     "text": "Another speech bubble"
>                 }, {
>                     "media": {
>                         "mediaName": "and an image",
>                         "mediaUri": "https://www.cm.com/cdn/web/nl-nl/blog/conversational-commerce.jpg",
>                         "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
>                     }
>                 }]
>             }
>         }]
>     }
> }
> ```

i want to make a post request with this **json_object** but i cant declare a json object in php so i should Convert My **json_object** to Array but i could not  convert this **json_object** to array without corrupting request data

this is my code

> ```
> $data = http_build_query($json_object);
> $ch = curl_init();
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
> $resp = curl_exec($ch);
> if($e = curl_error($ch)) {
>     echo $e;
> }
> else {
>     $decoded=json_decode($resp);
>     foreach($decoded as $key => $val) {
>         echo $key  . ':'. $val. '<br>';
>     }
> }
> curl_close($ch);
> ```

Can anyone help me sending this post request please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may want to use `json_encode()`.  Is `$json_object` a String?

Comment: Also, your JSON Object is correct. The primary issue I get is: *Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.* `$val` will be an Object and cannot be converted to String to be Echo'd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```
<?PHP
  $json_object = '{
    "messages": {
        "authentication": {
            "productToken": "your product token"
        },
        "msg": [{
            "body": {
                "type": "auto",
                "content": "Fallback Text for SMS"
            },
            "to": [{
                "number": "00316012345678"
            }],
            "from": "00316098765432",
            "allowedChannels": ["WhatsApp"],
            "richContent": {
                "conversation": [{
                    "text": "A text message with *bold* formatting in a speech bubble."
                }, {
                    "text": "Another speech bubble"
                }, {
                    "media": {
                        "mediaName": "and an image",
                        "mediaUri": "https://www.cm.com/cdn/web/nl-nl/blog/conversational-commerce.jpg",
                        "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}';
$decoded = json_decode($json_object);
foreach($decoded as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key: " . serialize($val) . '<br>';
}
?>
```

The result would be the following:

```
messages: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:14:"authentication";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:12:"productToken";s:18:"your product token";}s:3:"msg";a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":5:{s:4:"body";O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:4:"type";s:4:"auto";s:7:"content";s:21:"Fallback Text for SMS";}s:2:"to";a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:6:"number";s:14:"00316012345678";}}s:4:"from";s:14:"00316098765432";s:15:"allowedChannels";a:1:{i:0;s:8:"WhatsApp";}s:11:"richContent";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:12:"conversation";a:3:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:4:"text";s:57:"A text message with *bold* formatting in a speech bubble.";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:4:"text";s:21:"Another speech bubble";}i:2;O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:5:"media";O:8:"stdClass":3:{s:9:"mediaName";s:12:"and an image";s:8:"mediaUri";s:65:"https://www.cm.com/cdn/web/nl-nl/blog/conversational-commerce.jpg";s:8:"mimeType";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}}}}}}<br>
```

If there is a specific portion you want to address, you would need to target it from the current object.

If you want specific parts, you need to perform a lot of extra steps:

```
<?php
  $json_object = '{
    "messages": {
        "authentication": {
            "productToken": "your product token"
        },
        "msg": [{
            "body": {
                "type": "auto",
                "content": "Fallback Text for SMS"
            },
            "to": [{
                "number": "00316012345678"
            }],
            "from": "00316098765432",
            "allowedChannels": ["WhatsApp"],
            "richContent": {
                "conversation": [{
                    "text": "A text message with *bold* formatting in a speech bubble."
                }, {
                    "text": "Another speech bubble"
                }, {
                    "media": {
                        "mediaName": "and an image",
                        "mediaUri": "https://www.cm.com/cdn/web/nl-nl/blog/conversational-commerce.jpg",
                        "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}';
$decoded = json_decode($json_object);
foreach($decoded->messages->msg as $message){
    echo "To: " . $message->to[0]->number . "<br>\r\n";
    echo "From: " . $message->from . "<br>\r\n";
    foreach($message->richContent->conversation as $val){
        if(isset($val->text)){
            $txt = preg_replace("#\*([^*]+)\*#", "<b>$1</b>", $val->text);
            echo  $txt . "<br>\r\n";
        } elseif(isset($val->media)) {
            if($val->media->mimeType == "image/jpeg"){
                echo "<img src='{$val->media->mediaUri}' title='{$val->media->mediaName}'>\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This results in:

```
To: 00316012345678<br>
From: 00316098765432<br>
A text message with <b>bold</b> formatting in a speech bubble.<br>
Another speech bubble<br>
<img src="https://www.cm.com/cdn/web/nl-nl/blog/conversational-commerce.jpg" title="and an image">
```